# How to change text on UISwitch in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiswitch

I need to change the text on UISwitch and for that I have tried below code,

```
((UILabel *)[[[[[[_agreeAgb subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]).text = @"Foo";
((UILabel *)[[[[[[_agreeAgb subviews] lastObject] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]).text = @"Bar";
```

But It crashed at `objectAtIndex`

Is there any other way to do that other than making customized UISwitch?

Comment: Never use such hacking techniques to modify the built-in UIControls. In future, they may cease to work, in case, if the implementation of the controls change in the successive updates of iOS.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never use such hacking techniques to modify the built-in UIControls. In future, they may cease to work in case the implementation of the controls change in the successive updates of iOS.

If you want to customize `UISwitch` with your own text, you can instead you use `UISegmentedControl` with your new texts. For example, if you want to get the *gender* of the user, instead of changing the UISwitch's *on* and *off* labels text, you can use segmented control with two items "Male" & "Female".

Comment: Do check out [SVSegmentedControl](https://github.com/samvermette/SVSegmentedControl)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say *which* `objectAtIndex:` is causing the crash, but, in any case, it's moot: `UISwitch` does not currently allow customising of the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Now there's a better solution for this. Anyone needing a custom switch should check https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch

Answer (score 0):

Another option for a custom UISwitch: https://github.com/alexnauda/ERScrollSwitch